# Run Time Error 3704 MS Access VBA call iSeries Stored Procedure

Tags: vba, ms-access, db2

I'm working with MS Access 2013 and calling an IBM iSeries Stored Procedure, passing parameter values and appending the results to a local Access table.  This is my code:

```
Option Explicit
Dim Cm As New ADODB.Command
Dim C As New ADODB.Connection
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rsti400 As ADODB.Recordset
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim prm, prm1 As ADODB.Parameter
Dim i As Integer
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim rst, rst400 As DAO.Recordset
Private Declare Function MakeSureDirectoryPathExists Lib "imagehlp.dll" (ByVal lpPath As String) As Long
Dim CONO, SEA1, CUNO, TCCD, RCCD, ITNO, DATE, TLIST, RLIST, LR, TPRICE, RPRICE, FVDT, LVDT, SPUN, ERR, sHeader As String

Private Sub Command191_Click()
   'Define parameters
    CONO = "001"
    SEA1 = "2018SS"
    CUNO = ""
    TCCD = "GBP"
    RCCD = "GBP"
    ITNO = "ITEM123456"
    DATE = "00000000"
    TLIST = "0T"
    RLIST = "0S"
    LR = "Y"
    TPRICE = "0000000000"
    RPRICE = "0000000000"
    FVDT = "0000000000"
    LVDT = "0000000000"
    SPUN = ""
    ERR = ""

    'clear local table
   DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE tblIBM_Import.* FROM tblIBM_Import", -1

    'If C.State = adStateOpen Then C.Close

    C.Open "Driver=iSeries Access ODBC Driver;" & _
    "SYSTEM=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;UID=xxxxxx;PWD=xxxxxxx;"

    Cm.ActiveConnection = C

    Cm.CommandType = adCmdText

    Cm.CommandText = "{CALL QGPL.GETPRICESP(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}"

    Cm.Parameters.Append Cm.CreateParameter("CONO", adChar, adParamInput, 3, CONO)
    Cm.Parameters.Append Cm.CreateParameter("SEA1", adChar, adParamInput, 6, SEA1)
    Cm.Parameters.Append Cm.CreateParameter("CUNO", adChar, adParamInput, 10, CUNO)
    Cm.Parameters.Append Cm.CreateParameter("TCCD", adChar, adParamInput, 3, TCCD)
    Cm.Parameters.Append Cm.CreateParameter("RCCD", adChar, adParamInput, 3, RCCD)
    Cm.Parameters.Append Cm.CreateParameter("ITNO", adChar, adParamInput, 15, ITNO)
    Cm.Parameters.Append Cm.CreateParameter("DATE", adChar, adParamInput, 8, DATE)
    Cm.Parameters.Append Cm.CreateParameter("TLIST", adChar, adParamInput, 2, TLIST)
    Cm.Parameters.Append Cm.CreateParameter("RLIST", adChar, adParamInput, 2, RLIST)
    Cm.Parameters.Append Cm.CreateParameter("LR", adChar, adParamInput, 1, LR)
    Cm.Parameters.Append Cm.CreateParameter("TPRICE", adChar, adParamInput, 10, TPRICE)
    Cm.Parameters.Append Cm.CreateParameter("RPRICE", adChar, adParamInput, 10, RPRICE)
    Cm.Parameters.Append Cm.CreateParameter("FVDT", adBigInt, adParamInput, 8, FVDT)
    Cm.Parameters.Append Cm.CreateParameter("LVDT", adBigInt, adParamInput, 8, LVDT)
    Cm.Parameters.Append Cm.CreateParameter("SPUN", adChar, adParamInput, 3, SPUN)
    Cm.Parameters.Append Cm.CreateParameter("ERR", adChar, adParamInput, 1, ERR)

    ' Debug code to ensure parameters are set correctly
    For Each prm In Cm.Parameters
    Debug.Print prm.Name & " : " & prm.Value
    Next

    '=======================
    'Fetch data into Recordset
    '=======================

    'If rsti400.State = adStateOpen Then rsti400.Close

    Set rsti400 = Cm.Execute

    If rsti400.EOF Then

    MsgBox "The Recordset is empty"

    End If

    '=======================
    'Retrieve column headers
    '=======================
    i = 0
    sHeader = ""

    For i = 0 To rsti400.Fields.Count - 1
    sHeader = sHeader & rsti400.Fields.Item(i).Name & vbTab
    Next i
    'Debug.Print sHeader

    Set rst400 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblIBM_Import", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)

    'Loop through recordset and place values
    Do While rsti400.EOF = False

    With rst400
    .AddNew
    .Fields("CONO") = rsti400.Fields("CONO")
    .Fields("SEA1") = rsti400.Fields("SEA1")
    .Fields("CUNO") = rsti400.Fields("CUNO")
    .Fields("TCCD") = rsti400.Fields("TCCD")
    .Fields("RCCD") = rsti400.Fields("RCCD")
    .Fields("ITNO") = rsti400.Fields("ITNO")
    .Fields("DATE") = rsti400.Fields("DATE")
    .Fields("TLIST") = rsti400.Fields("TLIST")
    .Fields("RLIST") = rsti400.Fields("RLIST")
    .Fields("LR") = rsti400.Fields("LR")
    .Fields("TPRICE") = rsti400.Fields("TPRICE")
    .Fields("RPRICE") = rsti400.Fields("RPRICE")
    .Fields("FVDT") = rsti400.Fields("FVDT")
    .Fields("LVDT") = rsti400.Fields("LVDT")
    .Fields("SPUN") = rsti400.Fields("SPUN")
    .Fields("ERR") = rsti400.Fields("ERR")
    .Update

    End With
    rsti400.MoveNext
    Loop

    'close connections


    rsti400.Close
    rst400.Close
    C.Close

    Set rst400 = Nothing
    Set rsti400 = Nothing
    Set Cm = Nothing
    Set C = Nothing
End Sub
```

However, when I execute I receive the error:

Run Time Error 3704 - Operation is not allowed when the object is closed

The below code is then highlighted

```
If rsti400.EOF Then
```

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Where do you prepare before you execute?

Comment: Please use [`Option Explicit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw9t3484%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) and show all variable declarations with their object type.

Comment: I've added the declarations.  @mao - I don't fully understand - I'm just calling the SP and passing the parameters.

Comment: Do you need ` Cm.CommandType = amdCdStoredProc` ?

Comment: I just have it as text: Cm.CommandType = adCmdText

Comment: fyi: prm, rst and all the variables in the long Dim line (except sHeader) are declared as type Variant

Comment: are you sure?  e.g. Dim prm, prm1 As ADODB.Parameter

Comment: ok I declared on each line but still the same error

Comment: OK the issue is with the IBM Stored Procedure.  The last six parameters are defined as OUT and rest are defined as IN.  I need to amend how I call the Parameters.

This helps but isn't for VBA:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22617430/sql0469-in-out-or-inout-not-valid-for-parameter-2-in-procedure

Answer (score 0):

I got it working - the SP has OUT Parameters, so I had to assign these to fields:

```
Set rst400 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblIBM_Import", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)

With rst400
.AddNew
.Fields("ITNO") = cm.Parameters(5)
.Fields("TPRICE") = CCur(Left$(cm.Parameters(10), 8) & "." & Right$(cm.Parameters(10), 2))
.Fields("RPRICE") = CCur(Left$(cm.Parameters(11), 8) & "." & Right$(cm.Parameters(11), 2))
.Update

End With
```