# Cannot set output parameter direction or value for db2 proc call in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures, db2

I am trying to call a iSeries stored proc which return output params. Now while setting them as described in this article, the .Value or .Direction is not resolving. Also not sure how .Add is taking 3 parameters as given in the article. It accepts only one arg as object. Please advise.

[SQL0469 IN, OUT, or INOUT not valid for parameter 2 in procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22617430/sql0469-in-out-or-inout-not-valid-for-parameter-2-in-procedure)

```
using (IDbCommand cmd = database.CreateCommand("CALL PROCName" + "('" + RequestBody.SourceRequest.AccountNumber + "', ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", connection))
                {
    cmd.Parameters.Add("param", iDB2DbType.iDB2Char, 10); // error - Add accepts one arg
    cmd.Parameters["param"].Value = string.Empty; // not resolving
    cmd.Parameters["param"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output; // not resolving
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its your method for call procedure storage....

You must use Something like this:

```
DB2Connection conn1 = new DB2Connection("yourconnexionstring");
conn1.Open();

string callString5 = "YOURLIB.PROCName";

DB2Command cmd1 = new DB2Command(callString5, conn1);
cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

//here you must add all parameters necessary for your storage procedure
//respect order of all parameter


//first parameter
cmd1.Parameters.Add("param", iDB2DbType.iDB2Char, 10);
cmd1.Parameters["param"].Value = string.Empty;
cmd1.Parameters["param"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output; 

//second parameter


//etc.

cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery(); 

conn1.Close();
conn1.Dispose();
cmd1.Dispose();
```